# git: conflict while pulling changes when the same changes are already present in the working copy

Tags: git

I have the following setup: I am working on a PHP application deployed on a development server, but am editing the files on my local PC and uploading them one by one when they are changed. I could of course commit and push every single change and pull it to the server, but uploading them without involving git is far more convenient (I have a keyboard shortcut configured for it in my IDE). So, when I eventually commit & push my changes and pull them on the server, I will have the exact same changes in the "working copy" on the server and in the files I am trying to pull, but git will still tell me that there are conflicts and will refuse to pull the changes. Is there a way to handle this situation automatically? I can do `git checkout *` before `git pull` on the server, but in case there are some changes which are only on the server (unlikely, but who knows), these would then be lost, so this solution is not ideal...

Comment: can you explain why you don't systematically deploy a complete commt ?

Comment: @LeGEC: I tried, but maybe I wasn't explicit enough - in web development (especially when CSS is involved) you always have some trial & error, which (1) would lead to lots of commits with small changes that later may get reverted and (2) needs lots of deploys to the dev server, which makes doing it with git cumbersome, while uploading a file using SFTP is integrated in the IDE...

Answer (score 1):

*note* : your workflow seems awkward, you may want to look into how you deploy.

---

As far as git is concerned :

You can always run `git fetch` instead of `git pull` -- this will only update the `origin/*` branches, and try nothing on your active commit -- and then decide what to do :

- you can run `git diff origin/master` to check what are the differences between your worktree and what you just fetched
- if you are satisfied with the diff, you can run `git reset origin/master`, which would move the active commit without modifying (at all) the files in your worktree,
- you may run `git checkout .` or `git reset --hard HEAD` to discard all differences with the commit's content

Comment: Yeah, the workflow might sound awkward, but it's the best I could come up with within the constraints of this project (one of the constraints being that I can't easily set up a local environment to run the application in, so I always have to test it on the server). Thanks for the ideas! Maybe this can even be automated somehow, I'll try it out...

Comment: @rob74 : I think you could take the time to describe your setup in another question, and ask what other options you have. For the production part : manually copying files to the production server and then try to make it match git's commit will definitely lead you to an error sooner than later.

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding - I'm talking about a dev server here, not a production server! Of course I wouldn't ever do this on a production server, but for development it's more convenient to deploy the files without using git, it enables faster iteration...

Comment: @rob74 : ok, that's reassuring :) I don't fully get the "faster iteration" part though. Unless you're pushing a big amount of data on a painfully slow network connection (is it the case ?), you can script a `git push && ssh devserver "git fecth && git checkout"`, or a `git archive -o archive.tgz && scp archive.tgz devserver: && ssh devserver "tar -xf archive.tgz"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @LeGEC's answer, I now created a shell alias on the development server:

```
alias gitdiff='git fetch; git diff @{upstream}'
```

This fetches the changes from origin and then shows any differences between the working copy and the upstream version of the branch (ignoring the "local" version of the branch which isn't yet updated). So I can now type `gitdiff` and if it doesn't show any differences I know I can safely run `git checkout .` and `git pull` to have everything up to date.